# Setting up WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2

WSO2 folks,

I'm trying to setup WSO2 BAM following the User Guide: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator. But I got stuck on "Installing BAM Mediator Feature" section. I added a feature repository: http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.1.0, but couldn't find the feature "BAM Mediator Aggregate". The versions I'm using are:

WSO2 BAM:  2.3.0

WSO2 ESB:  4.6.0

So I suppose I should use Carbon 4.1.0 repository, is this correct? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "BAM Mediator Aggregate" feature is already installed on WSO2 ESB 4.6.0. The document is out dated.

Answer (score 0):

**Mediation Log**

1. Go in ESB Home > Configure > Mediation Data Publishing
2. enter
  BAM URL: https://bam_server_url:port(9443)
  Username: Username bam
  Password: Password bam
  and save
3. Go in BAM Home > Manage > BAM Toolbox
4. Add New Toolbox select Mediation Stats Monitoring Toolbox and install

**JMX Log**

1. Go in BAM Home > Manage > BAM Toolbox
2. Add New Toolbox select JMX Monitoring Toolbox and install
3. Go in Home > Configure > JMX Agent
4. Click "Add Default JMX Toolbox to monitor system resources of a WSO2 server running on Linux (CPU/Memory/OS)"
5. Click on "toolbox" Edit
6. enter
  *Data Receiver Information*
  Receiver address: ComboBox select "https" adress "bam_server:port(defult 9443)"
  Secure address: ComboBox select "https" adress "bam_server:port(defult 9443)"
  User Name: User BAM
  Password: Password BAM
  *JMX Server Information*
  Server URL: service:jmx:rmi:esb_esrver:11111/jndi/rmi:esb_esrver:9999/jmxrmi
  UserName: User ESB
  Password: Password ESB
  and save
7. Edit conf ESB wso2esb\repository\conf\etc\jmx.xml
  enter host(ip or domain name) esb_server
  <HostName>esb_server<HostName>